# Is there a way to fill a result of sparse data with 0 value points with Flux?

Tags: influxdb, flux-influxdb

I have points spread out every 5 min, and when the value is 0 the point is just omitted. I'd like to fill the omitted data with empty values.

I see with InfluxQL I could do:

```
group by time(5m) fill(0)
```

But I am using InfluxDB 2. I have tried this query:

```
      from(bucket:"%v")
         |> range(start: %d) 
         |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "volume" and r.id == "%v")
         |> window(every: 5m, period: 5m, createEmpty: true)
         |> fill(value: 0)
```

But it does not appear to be working.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this is a bug in InfluxDB related to https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/21857

Apparently the `window` function does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

#### [InfluxDB2] fill() sparse data with 0 points

had the same problem

Influxdb connects series without 0 ,here a cpu graph with missing timeframes
[image: Influxdb connects series without 0 ,here a cpu graph with missing timeframes]

- `fill()` only works on integers,
- non-existing datapoints can't be if-catched by value (...)
- `aggregateWindow()` finally helped

### Solution: InfluxDB2 null as zero (float())

```
from(bucket: "sys")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "docker_cpu_percent" )
//  |> window(every: 5m, period: 5m, createEmpty: true)
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 5m, fn: mean, createEmpty: true)
  |> map(fn: (r) => ({
      r with
      _value: if exists r._value then float(v: r._value) * 1.0  else 0.0
    })
  )
```

[image: Proper resonse from influx with null as 0 float() when using aggregateWindow()]

if you need your lines connected with larger `every`/`period` values ( e.g. 8h ), you might try to add `fill()` like this

```
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 4h, fn: distinct, createEmpty: true)
  |> fill(usePrevious: true)
```

### Resources

You might refer to

- the [InfluxDB aggregateWindow() documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/query-data/flux/window-aggregate/)
- [and for the if and map() usage in the query logic documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/query-data/flux/conditional-logic/)
- [the InfluxDB fill() function](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/fill/#parameters)

Answer (score 0):

The [fill](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/query-data/flux/fill/)() function only replaces nulls in the data and not missing data points based on time. At the moment there's no function available to this time, although one has been [requested](https://github.com/influxdata/flux/issues/2428).

What I've done over time periods where I need to fill in missing data is to generate a time series (with zero values) and join this with the time series with missing data.

Comment: I thought that `window(every: 5m, period: 5m, createEmpty: true)` would create null values for every 5 minute interval though?